# How to reference a image field and get it's file URI?

Tags: 8, entities, media, paragraphs

I have a paragraph type rn-accordion (rn-acc.html.twig), that has a entity reference revision to rn-accordion-section which houses a bunch of different fields. One of which is an image field (bp_image_field); however I am unsure how to reference this field in my twig file. So far I have tried:

```
      <img src="{{ file_url(paragraph.field_bp_image_field.fileuri) }}" class="img-responsive">

      <img src="{{ file_url(element['#object'].field_bp_image_field.0.entity.uri.value) }}" class="img-responsive">

      <img src="{{ file_url(content.field_bp_image_field['#items'].entity.uri.value) }}" class="img-responsive">
```

but the output is always

```
       <img src="/" class="img-responsive">
```

Can someone help steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not doing this, as you lose the benefits of image styles (the built-in image manipulation feature).

Suggesting you make a hook for this template, pick out the url from the source field, render an image with Drupal APIs, and make the result available as a variable on the template.

Comment: The images that will be referenced will all be the exact same size and never change, so image manipulation will not be required. Also, I should note that I am not an experienced Drupal developer, so while I appreciate your direction, examples that I could reverse engineer would be more helpful. Thanks.